# SQL subquerying issue. Cannot further refine result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Say there is a set of tables: (all column names mean the same across all tables)

- movie_award { title, award, result(either "won" or "nominated") }
- writer { id, title }
- person { id, first_name, last_name }

I cannot figure out an SQL query that: "Lists all writers who have written scripts ONLY for awarded movies.".

So any writer that has written for a movie that did not win an award, even if the writer has had award winning movies are not included.

Like the Venn diagram:

writers w/ only un-awarded movies || writers with both || **writers w/ only awarded movies**

I can get as far as, not sure if on the right track:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first_name, p.last_name, w.title
FROM writer w, person p, movie_award ma
WHERE w.id = p.id AND w.title = ma.title AND ma.result = 'won'
```

However this only returns the writers and movies that have won an award at some time. It doesn't limit to writers which ALL of their movies have won awards.

I'm open to different alternatives, ThankYou!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a query like below:

```
    SELECT p.first_name,
           p.last_name,
           w.title
    FROM   movie_award m
    INNER JOIN writer w
            ON m.title = w.title
               AND m.result = 'won'
    INNER JOIN person p
            ON w.id = p.id
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and I now understand what is going on, Thanks!!! On a side note, is it possible to rewrite this using sub-queries, instead of just joining :)

Comment: the query will also show writers who have not won an award for some other movie.

Comment: The writers themselves don't have the awards, the movie has the award of which I want to list the writer of the movie :)

Comment: @AndrewKeen : Yes, the above query can also be written using sub-queries.                                                                                                                             SELECT p.first_name,
       p.last_name
FROM   Person P
WHERE  P.ID IN (SELECT ID
                FROM   writer w
                WHERE  w.title IN (SELECT title
                                   FROM   movie_award m
                                   WHERE  m.result = 'won'))

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a [WHERE NOT EXISTS clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first_name, p.last_name, w.title
FROM writer w, person p
WHERE w.id = p.id
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM writer w2, movie_award ma
                WHERE w2.id = w.id AND w2.title = ma.title AND ma.result <> 'won')
```

Comment: This does work better, thanks! However on my test database somewhere in the joining processes it has created a tuple where it has paired a writer with a movie that they didn't even write :(